# How to change to python3 with atom using Anaconda?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, atom-editor

Currently I'm using Windows 10. I wanted to try out atom. The problem is that atom only uses the `python2` interpreter and I can't change it to use `python3`. Moreover I'm using python through the Anaconda installation.

- I already tried writing `runner: python: "~/Anaconda3"` in the atom configs.
- Also I already tried writing `process.env.PATH = ['~/anaconda3/bin', process.env.PATH].join(':')` in the `init.coffee`

The Anaconda2 and Anaconda3 folders're containing the `python.exe`
When I get the python version (`python --version`) it only shows the python2 version which atom is using. Is there any possibility to change the path for atom using Anaconda?
I'm using the script package in atom.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner/issues/124

Comment: Tried it already everything suggested out and it just won't work :(

Comment: [build-python](https://atom.io/packages/build-python) lets you switch between `python`, `python3` or any custom interpreter (obviously, I'm biased)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - I already tried writing runner: python: "~/Anaconda3" in the atom configs

If you're using the [`script` package](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script), then adding a config setting for the [`runner` package](https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner) isn't going to do any good.

Take a look at the [`script` README](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script#usage), in particular, it looks like you can achieve your desired result by utilizing profiles:

> Script: Configure Script should be used to configure command options, program arguments, and environment variables overrides. Environment variables may be input into the options view in the form VARIABLE_NAME_ONE=value;VARIABLE_NAME_TWO="other value";VARIABLE_NAME_3='test'.
>
> Also, in this dialog you can save options as a profile for future use. For example, you can add two profiles, one for python2.7 and another for python3 and run scripts with a specified profile, which will be more convinient than entering options every time you want to switch python versions.

Comment: I already find sth. about the profiles but actually didn't care about them. Now I tried it out and checked if python3 is realldy used and it is working. Sadly it seems like I can't change it to be the default interpreter but at least it is working. Thank you!